# Merge adjacent occurrences of identical elements in data collection

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++17, iteration, stl

There is a small [programming exercise](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/10/11/code-it-yourself-merging-consecutive-elements-in-a-c-collection/) to merge adjacent identical elements in a collection.

Here are two [solutions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b4f94f6e8fbaf66) (passing the tests from the exercise).
I am asking for review of the first version using standard algorithms.
The second is just for reference of the expected behavior.

```
template <typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename Equal, typename Merge>
void merge_adjacent(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, OutputIterator out, Equal equal, Merge merge)
{
    while(first != last){
    auto start = first;
    auto stop = std::find_if_not(start,last,[&](auto const &t){return equal(*start,t);});
    if(start != stop){
        out = std::accumulate(start+1,stop,*start,merge);
    }
    else{
        out = *start;
    }
    first = stop;
    }

    /*    
    while(first != last)
    {
        auto next = *first;
        first++;
        while((first != last) && (equal(next,*first)))
        {
            next = merge(next,*first);
            first++;
        }
        out = next;
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the data is sorted? If yes, then you could just [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) your way to the end.

Comment: I do not have an `compare`, only an `equal`. So the data is not sorted.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is `std::unique_copy()`, but instead of discarding duplicates, we have to use `merge` to combine them?

Comment: @Toby correct, but I want to clarify: We only merge adjacent duplicates and the element we push write to the output is the result of this merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally looks okay (though I would prefer shorter line lengths, and the indentation needs cleaning up).

It seems that we've focused on using `std::back_insert_iterator` as the output iterator; this leads to a couple of problems that are visible when we switch to a different iterator, such as a collection iterator or raw pointer:

- The caller doesn't know where the output finished; we should return the final value of `out`, just as `std::unique_copy()` does.
- The assignment `out =` neither indirects nor advances the iterator; it should be `*out++ =`.

We don't need a separate `start` copied from `first`, and we can use `std::adjacent_find` to determine the range of equal elements:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

template <typename ForwardIterator, typename OutputIterator,
          typename Equal, typename Merge>
OutputIterator merge_adjacent(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                              OutputIterator out,
                              Equal equal, Merge merge)
{
    while (first != last) {
        auto stop = std::adjacent_find(first, last, std::not_fn(equal));
        if (stop != last) {
            // advance to include the first of the pair
            ++stop;
        }
        *out++ = std::accumulate(first+1, stop, *first, merge);
        first = stop;
    }

    return out;
}
```

This version still performs two passes (one for the search, and one for the accumulate).  The commented-out, lower-level version of the function should be able to accept *input* iterators, as a single-pass algorithm.

Looking at that version, there's only a little to improve.  I'd probably post-increment the iterators while dereferencing, rather than as a separate statement, but that's just a style preference.  One thing I would change would be to use `std::move()` when finishing with `next`, to minimise unnecessary copying:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>

template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator,
          typename Equal, typename Merge>
OutputIterator merge_adjacent(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                              OutputIterator out,
                              Equal equal, Merge merge)
{
    while (first != last) {
        auto next = *first++;
        while (first != last && equal(next, *first)) {
            next = merge(std::move(next), *first++);
        }
        *out++ = std::move(next);
    }

    return out;
}
```